# YQL: empty result on getting friends list for private twitter account

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, yql

I use YQL:js for getting data.

I do in https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/:

```
select * from twitter.friends where id='some_not_private_account'
```

It works perfect. It returns friends list.
Now I do the same with a private account:

```
select * from twitter.friends where id='some_private_account' and 
oauth_consumer_key='some_key' and 
oauth_consumer_secret='some_secret' and 
oauth_token='some_token' and 
oauth_token_secret='some_token_secret'
```

There are not any error in debug but result section is empty. Why? What I'm doing wrong?

**#Update 1:**

Here is the xml answer with debug and diagnostics options:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2012-07-22T13:09:23Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <url execution-start-time="361" execution-stop-time="363"
            execution-time="2" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://www.datatables.org/twitter/twitter.friends.xml]]></url>
        <url execution-start-time="367" execution-stop-time="849"
            execution-time="482" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://zachgrav.es/twitter/yql/oauth.utils.js]]></url>
        <url execution-start-time="850" execution-stop-time="909"
            execution-time="59" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js]]></url>
        <url execution-start-time="912" execution-stop-time="943"
            execution-time="31" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/sha1.js]]></url>
        <url execution-start-time="965" execution-stop-time="1253"
            execution-time="288" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids/some_private_account.xml]]></url>
        <javascript execution-time="888" instructions-used="1032031" table-name="twitter.friends"/>
        <user-time>1254</user-time>
        <service-time>1187</service-time>
        <build-version>28958</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results/>
</query>
```

**Update 2:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuFw1.jpg

[image]

**Update 3:**
[My query](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&debug=true#h=select%20*%20from%20twitter.friends%20where%20id=%27scranthony%27)

Comment: Can you add debug=true&diagnostics=true to the YQL console URL and paste the diagnostics logs? That should help. The reason I ask is I want to make sure you are not hitting the rate limit or not.

Comment: @Karan Ashar thanks for your comment. I updated my post above

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I get different logs when I have debug=true.<url execution-start-time="343" execution-stop-time="448"
            execution-time="105" http-status-code="400"
            http-status-message="Bad Request"
            id="999f49d8-714a-4962-b225-849f279d83c8" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids/JoeyBats19.xml]]></url>. The above is a part of the diagnostics with debug=true (Ignore the bad request). Notice the  id="999f49d8-714a-4962-b225-849f279d83c8". The id is a clickable url which gives us the logging dump from the API. I hope I made sense here :)

Comment: @Karan Ashar I don't get any id. How did you get it?  I tried it for my twitter account api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids/scranthony.xml

Comment: Refer to the YQL documentation [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-network-logging.html). Follow the steps there. Make sure in the YQL console URL, you have debug=true

Comment: @KaranAshar Thanks for your response. Here is my url with debug option: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20twitter.friends%20%20where%20id%3D'scranthony'&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&debug=true  But I cannot get ID there.

Comment: Oh I see whats happening here. You are trying the REST query. The result of this query will not show the id because these id's are hyperlinks and will increase the response size. That's my 2 cents. Try directly at the YQL console [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&debug=true#h=select%20*%20from%20twitter.friends%20where%20id%3D%27scranthony%27) That should definitely work.

Comment: Unfortunately not =(. I added print screen to post.

Comment: That is strange. The one issue in the print screen i see is the http-status-code 400 and "Bad Request" to http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids/scranthony.xml. Looking at the id that I get (weird), I see <error>Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.</error>

Comment: yes. It because of my account is private and I'm doing authorization without oauth. It is just example to show you that I haven't any id. It's really strange. Could you try to run my query in update3 please. Do you see id option there?

Comment: Tried running that. Still get the rate limit exceeded error in the above comment. Still strange you don't get the id though.